# Meteor Update collection - Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I am Learnign Meteor and came across this situation i was following along a Meteor tutorial on tuts plus. the code is exactly the same in video the update of collection occurs but in my browser it shows this error:

Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

The code is here:

```
Template.person.events({
'click': function (e, t) {
  Session.set("edit-"+ t.data._id, true);
},
'keypress input': function(e,t){
  if(e.keyCode === 13){

    var docid = Session.get("edit-"+ this._id);
    People.update(t.data, {$set: {name: e.currentTarget.value}});
    Session.set("edit-"+ t.data._id, false);
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For code that runs on the client side/browser side you can only use an `_id` field as the query. On the server you can run it as you please.

Modify your code so you get the document first then use its `_id` to perform an update.

```
var person = People.findOne(t.data);

People.update({_id: person._id}, {$set: {name: e.currentTarget.value}});
```

I assume `t.data` is some kind of query? If its an `_id` try using `{_id: t.data` as the query instead. Either way so long as the selector of the `update` **only** uses an `_id`  it should be fine.

The reason this might work on the tutorial you're following is this change was introduced more recently to lock down security.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue and this answer really helped me.

Comment: Seems to throw the issue if you have the _id and also MORE filtering mechanisms.

Comment: @NormanH yes this would be so, the _id can match one document only. You can use any query for the first `findOne`

Answer (score 0):

```
  Template.person.events({
    'click': function (e, t) {
      Session.set('edit-' + t.data._id, true);
    },
    'keypress input' : function(e, t) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        People.update(t.data._id, { $set: { name: e.currentTarget.value }});
        Session.set('edit-' + t.data._id, false);
      }
    }
  });
```